# How to understand and use DSolve solution

Tags: differential-equations, system-variables

This equation is simple to `DSolve` in *Mathematica*, but I don't know how to use and understand solution.

```
 DSolve[Y1''[x] - a2 Y1[x] - a1*X1[x] == 0, Y1[x], x]
```

$ \text{Y1}[x]\to e^{\sqrt{\text{a2}} x} C[1]+e^{-\sqrt{\text{a2}} x} C[2]+e^{-\sqrt{\text{a2}} x} \left(e^{2 \sqrt{\text{a2}} x} \int_1^x \frac{\text{a1} e^{-\sqrt{\text{a2}} K[1]} \text{X1}[K[1]]}{2 \sqrt{\text{a2}}} \, dK[1]+\int_1^x -\frac{\text{a1} e^{\sqrt{\text{a2}} K[2]} \text{X1}[K[2]]}{2 \sqrt{\text{a2}}} \, dK[2]\right) $

What is `dK1` and `dK2`, how to solve integrals [1,x], and how to use this solution `Y1[x]` to find `X1[x]` in another equation

```
Derivative[2][X1][x] == Y1[x]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `dK[2]` just means the integral is with respect to `K[2]`,

$\int f(t) dt$ is exactly the same as $\int f(K[2]) dK[2]$

In this case, it appears in the solution because `X1[x]` is an unknown, so the only way for the differential equation to be formally solved is to include how it would affect the solution via the integrals.  However, you can solve for `x1` at the same time:

```
sol = DSolve[{
   y1''[x] - a2 y1[x] - a1 x1[x] == 0,
   x1''[x] == y1[x]},
  {y1[x], x1[x]}, x]
```

Since no initial conditions are supplied the result has a bunch of arbitrary constants called `C[i]` in this case there are four of them.

Here's an example using the result to create two functions `f,g` that correspond to `y1,x1` with some specific constants:

```
Clear[f, g]
params = {a1 -> 1., a2 -> -2., C[1] -> 3., C[2] -> -3., C[3] -> 2., C[4] -> 3.};
f[x_] = y1[x] /. sol /. params;
g[x_] = x1[x] /. sol /. params;
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plot]