# DSolve yields a strange character K[1]

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a linear differential equation as in the following code:

```
DSolve[x'[t] == a + b E^(g t) + (c + d E^(-g t)) x[t], x[t], t]
```

which yields

[image]

`K[1]` in the integral term is mysterious. I looked at [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/369340) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18752/how-to-understand-and-use-dsolve-solution), but wasn't able to find a solution. I couldn't find anything in my equation that makes it uncomputable.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `1` in `K[1]` just means it's the first integration dummy variable needed. If you had many you'd get `K[1], K[2], ...`

Comment: Now that they've got the generated constant formerly known as `C[1]` nicely formatted, they should do something similar with the `K[1]`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes from integrating the ODE

The ODE to solve is
\begin{align*}
{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right) =a+b{{\rm e}^{gt}}+ \left( c+d{{\rm e}^{-gt}} \right) x \left( t \right) 
\end{align*}

In canonical form, the ODE is written as
\begin{align*}
             x' &= F(t,x)\\ 
                          &= {{\rm e}^{-gt}}dx+b{{\rm e}^{gt}}+cx+a
\end{align*}

The ODE is linear in $x$ and has the form
$$
   x' = x f(t) + g(t)
$$
Where $f(t) = c+d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}$ and $g(t) = b{{\rm e}^{gt}}+a$.

Writing the ODE as
\begin{align*} 
                 x' - \left( \left( c+d{{\rm e}^{-gt}} \right) x\right) &= b{{\rm e}^{gt}}+a\\   
                 x' - \left( c+d{{\rm e}^{-gt}} \right) x &= b{{\rm e}^{gt}}+a
\end{align*}
Therefore the integrating factor $\mu$ is
$$ 
                \mu = e^{\int -c-d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}} = {{\rm e}^{-ct+{\frac {d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}}
$$
The ode becomes
\begin{align*}
               \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}}}{ \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}} \mu x &= \mu \left(b{{\rm e}^{gt}}+a\right)   \\ 
               \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}}}{ \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}} \left(x{{\rm e}^{-ct+{\frac {d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}}\right) &=  \left( b{{\rm e}^{gt}}+a \right) {{\rm e}^{-ct+{\frac {d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}}\\ 
                 \mathrm{d} \left(x{{\rm e}^{-ct+{\frac {d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}}\right)  &=  \left( \left( b{{\rm e}^{gt}}+a \right) {{\rm e}^{-ct+{\frac {d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}}\right) \mathrm{d} t
\end{align*}
Integrating both sides gives
\begin{align*}
             x{{\rm e}^{-ct+{\frac {d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}} &= \int \! \left( b{{\rm e}^{gt}}+a \right) {{\rm e}^{-ct+{\frac {d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}}\,{\rm d}t + C_1
\end{align*}
Dividing both sides by the integrating factor $\mu={{\rm e}^{-ct+{\frac {d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}}$
results in
$$
              x = {1\int \! \left( b{{\rm e}^{gt}}+a \right) {{\rm e}^{-ct+{\frac {d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}}\,{\rm d}t \left( {{\rm e}^{-ct+{\frac {d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}} \right) ^{-1}}+{{\it \_C1} \left( {{\rm e}^{-ct+{\frac {d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}} \right) ^{-1}}
$$
Simplifying the solution gives
$$
x={{\rm e}^{{\frac {ctg-d{{\rm e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}} \left( \int \! \left( b{{\rm e}^{gt}}+a \right) {{\rm e}^{-{\frac { \left( ctg{{\rm e}^{gt}}-d \right) {{\rm e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}}\,{\rm d}t+{\it \_C1} \right) 
$$

Now, instead of writing $\int \!b{\mathrm{e}^{{\frac{-ctg+{g}^{2}t+d{\mathrm{%
e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}}+{\mathrm{e}^{{\frac{-ctg+d{\mathrm{e}^{-gt}}}{g}}}}a\,%
\mathrm{d}t$, Mathematica wrties as 
\begin{equation*}
\int_{1}^{t}b{\mathrm{e}^{{\frac{-cKg+{g}^{2}K+d{\mathrm{e}^{-gK}}}{g}}}}+%
{\mathrm{e}^{{\frac{-cKg+d{\mathrm{e}^{-gK}}}{g}}}}a\,\mathrm{d}K
\end{equation*}

i.e. it uses $K[n]$ as dummy variable of integration inside the integral. That
is all. The choice of 1 as lower limit vs. 0 is arbitrary. Mathematica always uses 1 for lower limit in such cases.

Comment: Thanks so much! So, when I `Plot` the solution along with parameter values assigned, I should get concrete value for $t=1,2,3,\cdots$, right? But Mathematica doesn't compute the integral for $t=1,2,3,\cdots$ but simply reproduce the integral with $t=1,2,3,\cdots$ in the output. For example, I tried `x[1]` and I don't get any specific value. (Of course, I assigned values for the other parameters.

Comment: @ppp you can't plot the solution as is, since there is an unknown constant of integration in it. You need to have an initial condition specified to get specific solution to plot.

Comment: Yes, as just mentioned, I assigned specific values for all unknown constants of integration, i.e. $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $g$, and $C_1$. Then I should be able to plot the solution, right? But it doesn't work...

Comment: @ppp In this case, yes, it should work. I do not know why. May you are making a mistake somewhere. May be you can post a separate question on this if you want.

Comment: I have created a new post on this [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202574/plot-the-solution-from-dsolve). Can you please help me once more? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Nasser What is the meaning of the 1 in K[1] here?  Is it being treated as an input to a function K, or does it have any other significance?

Comment: @user10478  `K[1]` means it is indexed symbol. Mathematica uses `C[1]` and `C[2]` and `K[1]` and `K[2]` etc... as reserved for internal constants of integration and other purposes where it needs to make a constant. It is not an actual function, just an indexed variable. One is the index. That is why it is not good idea to use `C` or `K` for own variables. Only use lower case symbols.

Comment: Can someone explain why the choice between 0 and 1 for the lower bound is arbitrary...? Seems like it will change the answer.

Comment: @pretzlstyle  it is the same answer mathemtically. if one uses 0 or 1 for the lower limit. Since the difference can always be absorbed/added to the integration constant $c_1$. I do not know why Mathematica choose 1 instead of zero. May be because Mathematica was written by Physics folks initially, and Physics people do strange things with integrals.

Comment: @Nasser oohh, gotcha, makes sense. Thanks!